# CSS Hover state stays in Safari after changing the HTML of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I've got a very simple `span` element which contains just text:

```
<span class="myspan">Some Text</span>
```

It has a CSS hover state which adds some `border`:

```
.myspan:hover { border: 1px solid #BCBEC4; }
```

I'm using jQuery to change the HTML of the `span` on click - like changing to a dropdown. After clicking in the dropdown, I would change the HTML back to the original value.

Such as:

```
$('span.myspan').html('Some Text')
```

All works on all browsers, but on Safari the `span` will still have the `:hover` state, even if the mouse-pointer is not in the span.

Only hovering again will remove this state.

**P.S - It works fine on any other browser but on Safari it is not working properly.**

EDIT: I've create a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/242qd/1/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate this?

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue (safari+hover). Here is a small article I found, maybe it'll give you some helpful pointers. http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/

Comment: Added a fiddle - the e.StopPropogation() creates the problem - but is needed there as can be seen in the fiddle

Comment: @Gil Thanks - but the articles is about Touch devices. I'm using a Safari on a Mac

Comment: @Roman have you found any fix for this ? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

remove dot in front of span tag and try

```
$('span.myspan').html('Some Text')
```

Comment: Thanks - but that was just a typo

Comment: I understand why the jquery is incorrect but I fail to see how this will correct the hover behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I wouldn't say this works in any browser.  Because you're simply changing the HTML the css hover rule still applies to the span tag that now (invalidly) holds an unordered list.  (And, in this example, this also causes the whole list to bounce around a lot in every browser, but I suppose if there was a background applied to the ul this might not be the case.)

More importantly, this becomes very difficult to maintain and update, because your html is in the script.  If I can suggest an alternative:
1. Place your elements in the DOM and hide them with display: none.
2. Use one jQuery's many show/hide methods (show/fadeIn/toggle) to show and hide your elements in whatever event handler you want.

Here's just one way to do that (based on your example, so the actual code may not be perfect for your exact needs):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/Q4ysG/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span.myspan').on('click', function () {
       $(this).next().show(); //this way of traversal works fine for this example, your real code may vary depending on it's structure.
       $(this).hide();        
    });

    $('.links').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev().show();
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="myspan">My HTML</span>

<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="javascript:makesome();">Some link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Some link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Some link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Some link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Some link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
span.myspan:hover {
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.links {
    display:none;
}
```

Oh yeah, and this doesn't require stopping propagation of the events (which you should generally avoid as much as possible).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate example - though this might create a fix by re-writing the code, it still doesn't solve the original question - as it seems the problem is in Safari itself - as it works OK in other browsers.

Comment: As I said, at least in your example, I don't consider this working in any browser because it produces invalid markup.  Also, the example follows what are generally considered bad practice.  Sorry, it's the CTO in me, I can't overlook those things...blame it on a lifetime of code reviews... :-(

Comment: To put this into better context - This part is a part of a large BackboneJS based app, where the HTML that is loaded is actually dynamic one based on a Backbone view - Thus your approach will require very serious code refactoring. That's the reason I'm looking to solve this with the current code with minimum changes

Comment: I understand, and I wish I had some magic that would make it work for you.  Much luck.